# C++ Error: Redeclaration of double TOTAL_CALORIES previously redclare here

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> //round numbers
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{

 //Declare
const double ONE_COOKIES = 75.0;
double ATE_COOKIES;
double TOTAL_CALORIES;

 //Output of program
    cout << " Input how many cookies you ate (eg, 3 & 5): " << endl; 
    cin >> ATE_COOKIES;


 // Round numbers
    cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << ATE_COOKIES << endl;

 //Formula  
    double TOTAL_CALORIES = ATE_COOKIES * ONE_COOKIES;

 //Results
 cout << " One cookie is equal to " << ONE_COOKIES << " caloreis " << " And you ate "     << double caloreis << " of cookies" << endl; 



 system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is a c++ program that i made trying to compute the program. Im having trouble computing the program so i'm asking for help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is clear. You declared `TOTAL_CALORIES` twice.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot re declare TOTAL_CALORIES. the `double` identifier is ONLY used why creating a variable.

the statement *should* be `TOTAL_CALORIES = ATE_COOKIES * ONE_COOKIES;` as you are only assigning a value to `TOTAL_CALORIES`, not declaring the variable.

This also seems to apply to your cout statement, when you're simply using the variable you **dont** need to specify it's type, you told the compiler once and that's all you need to do.

```
int thing  = 0;
thing = 4; //just assign a value
cout << thing << endl; //print the value
```

on a side not you should avoid using all caps in your variables. This commonly represents a constant in a program. Try using camel case or all lowercase naming mutable variables.